# Why I am getting AttributeError: 'process_simulation' object has no attribute 'action_space'/ observation_space?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, simulation, reinforcement-learning

Although action_space & observation_space are defined in the process_simulation function.  I am stuck in this situation for my project work. Please help me in this regard. I want to use a custom environment for Deep Reinforcement Learning with OpenAI Gym and Python. I want to implement a proximal policy optimization(PPO) model to train the agent.

`from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import numpy as np
import random

class process_simulation(Env):
def *init*(self):

```
    self.simulation_duration = 60
    self.time_step = 1
    self.next_time_stop = 0
    
    self.setup_time = 0
    self.buffer_capacity = 99999
    self.initial_buffer = 0
    self.initial_reward = 0
    
    self.process_time_of_product_a = [5,4,3,3,1]
    self.process_time_of_product_b = [1,2,3,4,5]
    self.process_time_of_product_c = [3,5,1,4,2]
    
    self.default_standard_deviation = .0
    
    
    self.fifo_list = []
    
    
    self.time_to_get_raw_material = 1
    self.cost_for_machining = 0
    self.cost_for_storage = 1
    self.cost_for_raw_material = 50
    
    
    self.finished_jobs_machine1 = 0
    self.finished_jobs_machine2 = 0
    self.finished_jobs_machine3 = 0
    self.finished_jobs_machine4 = 0
    self.finished_jobs_machine5 = 0
    
    
    self.consecutive_production_of_product_a = 0
    self.consecutive_production_of_product_b = 0
    self.consecutive_production_of_product_c = 0
    self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a = 0
    self.consecutive_switches_to_product_b = 0
    self.consecutive_switches_to_product_c = 0
    self.consecutive_idle_states = 0
    
    self.rl_agent_actions = [0,1,2,3]
    self.rl_agent_reward = self.initial_reward
    self.state = dict()
    
    self.observation_size = 3
    self.action_size = len(self.rl_agent_actions)
    self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0]), high=np.array([100]))
    self.action_space = Discrete(3)
    
def _get_next_job(self,finished_jobs):
    return self.fifo_list[finished_jobs]

def _apply_variability(self,process_time):
    return random.gauss(process_time,process_time*self.default_standard_deviation)

def _calculate_sales_value(self,product_type):
    
    if product_type=='A':
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_a += 1
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_b = 0
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_c = 0
        if self.consecutive_production_of_product_a ==1:
            self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a +=1
            return min(400, 200*(1.5**(self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a)))
        else:
            self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a = 0
            return max (100, 200*(.5**(self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a-2)))
        
    elif product_type=='B':
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_b += 1
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_a = 0
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_c = 0
        if self.consecutive_production_of_product_b ==1:
            self.consecutive_switches_to_product_b +=1
            return min(400, 200*(1.5**(self.consecutive_switches_to_product_b)))
        else:
            self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a = 0
            return max (100, 200*(.5**(self.consecutive_switches_to_product_b-1)))
        
    elif product_type=='C':
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_c += 1
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_a = 0
        self.consecutive_production_of_product_b = 0
        if self.consecutive_production_of_product_c ==1:
            self.consecutive_switches_to_product_c +=1
            return min(400, 200*(1.5**(self.consecutive_switches_to_product_c)))
        else:
            self.consecutive_switches_to_product_a = 0
            return max (100, 200*(.5**(self.consecutive_switches_to_product_c)))
    
    
    else:
        raise ValueError('{} --> requested type is not in the list of allowed product types [A, B , C]'.format(product_type))
        
        
def _run_machine_1(self):
    while True:
        jobs = len(self.fifo_list)
        if (jobs==0) or (jobs==self.finished_jobs_machine1):
            yield self.timeout(self.time_step)
            
        else:
            next_job = self._get_next_job(self.finished_jobs_machine1)
            if jobs==1:
                yield self.timeout(self.setup_time)
            elif self.fifo_list[self.finished_jobs_machine1-1] != next_job:
                yield self.timeout(self.setup_time)
            
            if next_job=='A':
                yield self.timeout(self.time_to_get_raw_material)
                yield self.raw_material_of_product_a.get(1)
                self.reward -= self.cost_for_machining*self.process_time_of_product_a[0]
                yield self.timeout(self._apply_variability(self.process_time_of_product_a[0]))
                yield self.raw_material_machine1_product_a.put(1)
                self.finished_jobs_machine1 +=1
                
            elif next_job=='B':
                yield self.timeout(self.time_to_get_raw_material)
                yield self.raw_material_of_product_b.get(1)
                self.reward -= self.cost_for_machining*self.process_time_of_product_b[0]
                yield self.timeout(self._apply_variability(self.process_time_of_product_b[0]))
                yield self.raw_material_machine1_product_b.put(1)
                self.finished_jobs_machine1 +=1
                
            elif next_job=='C':
                yield self.timeout(self.time_to_get_raw_material)
                yield self.raw_material_of_product_c.get(1)
                self.reward -= self.cost_for_machining*self.process_time_of_product_c[0]
                yield self.timeout(self._apply_variability(self.process_time_of_product_c[0]))
                yield self.raw_material_machine1_product_c.put(1)
                self.finished_jobs_machine1 +=1
                
            else:
                raise ValueError('{} --> requested type is not in the list of allowed product types [A, B, C]'.format(next_job))
                env = process_simulation()
                observation_dimensions = env.observation_space.shape[0]
                num_actions = env.action_space.n`
```

Comment: Could you provide a traceback of the error?

Comment: runfile('D:/Hiwi/Task-1/untitled0.py', wdir='D:/Hiwi/Task-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File D:\Hiwi\Task-1\untitled0.py:457 in <module>
    observation_dimensions = env.observation_space.shape[0]

AttributeError: 'process_simulation' object has no attribute 'observation_space'

Comment: And where does `process_simulation()` originate from?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: It is the class at the beginning. The only class for my simulation. I have defined observation_size/observation_space int the class but it is giving me this error.

Comment: I am calling this process_simulation into another class, then it is giving me the error.

Comment: So could you show the code related to `process_simulation`?

Comment: I have another error called "NotImplementedError". Can you please help me?

Comment: I would close this issue and open a new one with all relevant details.

Comment: That one is also solved. Another error arises :(

Comment: I have write "state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)" this line. Then the following error comes:
TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got NoneType)

Comment: Where and as what did you define `state`?

Comment: def select_action(self, state):

Comment: Can you please open a new question with a detailed error log and relevant parts of your code? These descriptions are far too little to go off of. `state` is not defined there, it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I have changed to "state = torch.tensor(state).float().unsqueeze(0)" this then another error showed up "RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of NoneType"

Comment: Yes, you already mentioned that, but you used `state` in the tensor function. What is its value?

Comment: I have tried but I could not open a new question:(

Comment: Then try to add the new information to this question.